# Linear Regression - How to predict two variables

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I trying to use the dummy variables (flv1, h264, mpeg4) to predict the (umem and utime). Any suggestions on how to predict two outcomes based on a single categorical variable?

[image: Dataset]

This is what I have done so far. Whenever i try to run the fit function, python just returns LinearRegression() with no attributes.

[image: Progress so far]

Comment: the model is fitted. what do you need to do next?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that.

Let's look at the columns ["flv1", "h264", "mpeg4"]. They were constructed from a single categorical variable, which means that there are only 3 possibilities for values in these three columns: (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), but there are 4890 different values for "umem" and "utime".
For example, look at rows with indices 0, 3, 4887 --> in all cases, flv1 = 0, h264 = 1, mpeg4 = 0, but the values for "umem" and "utime" are significantly different.

For starters, you can calculate the mean/std/distribution for "umem" and "utime" variables for each of the values for the categorical variable. In other words, I would create three dataframes from the original one (based on value in the ladt three columns), and analyze them separately, to see how are the values for "umem" and "utime" distributed for each value of the categorical variable).

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, you called the `fit()` method of your Linear Regression but for predict you need to call the `predict()` method after `fit()`.

Secondly, you want to predict multiple outcomes, a Linear Regression is adapted for predict a single outcome.
You should look *Multiclass and multioutput algorithms* from scikit-lear who contains
some [multioutput-regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-regression) algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Is "codec" the data column that you want to use as reference to predict "umem" and "utime" ? If so, you need a pipeline for this.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

std_scaler = StandardScaler() 
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_regressor = Pipeline([
    ("std_scaler", std_scaler),
    ("lin_reg", lin_reg),
])

X = df[['umem', 'utime']]
y_train_predict = df['codec']

def learning_curves(regressor, X, y): 
    
    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=55) 
                                                                                            
    train_errors, val_errors = [], []
    
    for m in range(2, len(X_train)):
        regressor.fit(X_train[:m], y_train[:m])
        y_train_predict = regressor.predict(X_train[:m])
        y_val_predict = regressor.predict(X_val)
        train_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_train[:m], y_train_predict))
        val_errors.append(mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_predict))
    
    # this part is just for the plot setting
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(train_errors), "r-", linewidth=2, label="train")
    plt.plot(np.sqrt(val_errors), "b-", linewidth=3, label="val")
    plt.legend(loc="upper right", fontsize=14)   
    plt.xlabel("Training set size", fontsize=14) 
    plt.ylabel("RMSE", fontsize=14)              
    plt.axis([0, 60, 0, 20]) 
    plt.show() 
    
    print(np.sqrt(train_errors)[-1], np.sqrt(val_errors)[-1])
    return X_train, y_train

X_train, y_train = learning_curves(lin_regressor, X, y_train_predict)
```

In this case, you predict the data in "umem" and "utime" compare to "codec". You don't need to convert "codec" to dummy variables.